# How to change file name when download it from server in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I download a file using below code in AngularJS

```
 $scope.download = function (row) {
        var url = row.entity.downloadUrl;
        window.open(url, "_blank");
 };
```

The `url` is an image from file serve.How could I change/set the file name when I download it without using the name from file server.

I do not want to use any plugin,is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `a` html attribute and use that to `download` your file.

```
var file_path = 'row.entity.downloadUrl';
var a = document.createElement('A');
a.href = file_path;
a.download = 'you new file name';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
```